# "Destination Host Unreachable" when pinging directly connected computer after IP change

Tags: centos, networking, ping

Issue:
After changing the static IP addresses on 2 units, I can no longer ping.

Configuration:
OS: CentOS 7

Interfaces:

- 2 1-GbE adapters, one used, connects to the Internet, DHCP, works
- 2 10-GbE fiber channel adapters, one used, direct connect

Details:

I originally had the 10 GbE connections use "10.10.10.10" on one board and "10.10.10.11" on the other board. The default gateway did not matter, but I simply used "10.10.10.10". I set the MTU to 9000, prefix at 24, and disabled IPv6. Everything worked perfectly. I did not need to edit the hosts file.

After I changed the IP addresses on both units, a requirement made down upon me. One unit received an IP address of "11.33.41.15" and a default gateway of "11.33.41.0", while the other unit received an IP address of "15.5.53.51" and a default gateway of "15.5.53.254".

I keep getting a destination host unreachable, and nothing that I have tried gets me to connect the two units, still directly connected to each other.

I tried adding adding a permanent route by creating a [permanent route](http://elearning.wsldp.com/pcmagazine/add-permanent-routes-centos-7/), and sadly the script did not yield a success.

I tried adding the two NICs to the [hosts file](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap9sec95.html), although that has nothing to do with route determination. I do not have a domain, so just IP1/"computer1" and IP2/"computer2". Adding the hosts file entries enables me to do "ping -c 3 computer2" from computer1 nicely, but still same message.

The interface definition is fine, works, comes up, all is good, but here is the interface file from computer2:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=ens2f0
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:0F:53:2A:18:B0
UUID=07f81988-6828-4b46-938a-72f70121e5a5
MTU=1500
IPADDR=15.5.53.51
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=15.5.53.254
```

Here is the hosts file from computer2.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1             localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
11.33.41.15     computer1
15.5.53.51      computer2
```

From previous experience, I did both reboot the computer and subsequently turned off the computers and then back on, but same thing.

Thoughts?

Comment: unless you are using the IPv6, remove the line starting with `::1` from your hosts files. I saw this removal working miracles, reasons of which I am not so sure.

Comment: @MelBurslan I tried that, but did not reboot/restart nework. Same thing. I am not using IPV6, just IPV6.

Comment: _IP address of "11.33.41.15" and a default gateway of "11.33.41.0"_  What is the netmask of this?  Because if it's just a /24 then the gateway is not valid.

Comment: @StephenHarris The two machines will be in different cities, but I wanted to test the 2 machines locally with their final IP addresses, so that the machines can be just plug and play. I also have a bit more to test and configure in other areas.

Comment: @SarahWeinberger`service network restart` after removing the IPv6 entries might be helpful. I am not sure. Grasping on straws here.

Comment: @MelBurslan I put the network back to triple 10 and restarted the servers and all is fine again. I will just do my testing and tweaking using the triple 10, but change to the real thing prior to shipping, just I would like to know what I am missing/not understanding technically, so that I do not give something that they have to debug. Also, this issue will come up. Obviously, the problem is something with what Stephen Harris said.

Comment: Oh, @MelBurslan, the 24-subnet mask came from the end customer, not me. Each unit is probably on a /24 network, but connected via WAN. I am just missing something in my understanding of connecting via WAN and 2 different subnets. Maybe that has to go through a switch and cannot have the fiber cable directly going box to box in house.